# How to classify speech sound by characteristics using AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

What functions exist for **classifying speech sounds** by deriving values from *Python* or *JavaScript*?

We know that speech has characteristics: *speech sounds, tone, noise, pitch, strength, sound duration, fundamental tone, overtone, timbre and formant*. Therefore, it is necessary to determine the values for each characteristic with the use of some algorithm. **TensorFlow** has no such possibility, as it can only classify sounds according to their general character: crying, screaming, vocal, ect.